# Daloradius - Class 'DB' not found, but "pear/DB" is deprecated

Tags: pear

I run Centos 7, FreeRADIUS 3.0.4, PHP 5.4.16, httpd Apache/2.4.6.

I can log into the Daloradius login screen and then get ERROR 500 on the browser on the ../daloradius/dologin.php page.

Errors in the php log:

```
[Fri Apr 07 15:59:48.455964 2017] [:error] [pid 2145] [client 154.66.144.101:53132] PHP Warning:  include_once(DB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/daloradius/library/opendb.php on line 84, referer: http://server/daloradius/login.php
[Fri Apr 07 15:59:48.456091 2017] [:error] [pid 2145] [client 154.66.144.101:53132] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'DB.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/daloradius/library/opendb.php on line 84, referer: http://server/daloradius/login.php
[Fri Apr 07 15:59:48.456241 2017] [:error] [pid 2145] [client 154.66.144.101:53132] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DB' not found in /var/www/html/daloradius/library/opendb.php on line 86, referer: http://server/daloradius/login.php
```

*"server" is just a placeholder for our real FQDN.*

I read that the fix is to install Pear DB, but it is depricated so I installed MDB2 and its MySQLi driver.

Please assist in a solution, I am *very* new to this system..

Comment: You can't just install some random thing and hope it works. You'll need to install Pear DB, which I suspect was not deprecated back when DaloRADIUS's last version was released.  Alternatively you'll need to find a newer RADIUS management tool.

Comment: Thanks for the advice DerfK. The documentation on Pear DB explained to use MDB2 instead because it is the replacement. I will post the findings if I get it to work or move on.

Comment: Resolving to install the complete DaloRADIUS image (including OS, PHP etc.) so it will work out of the box.

Comment: Be careful with the image, it's probably missing at least three years of security patches, and updating it may break things.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, daloRADIUS has not been maintained. Anything that's part of your security infrastructure needs constant attention. You really want to seriously consider if you want to rely on a package that's ostensibly dead. If you are not a coder and capable of owning 100% maintenance of your own fork of the codebase there is no way on earth I would recommend you ever consider using it for anything mission critical.

Yes, DB is deprecated - although I believe they are still doing security patches on it to support legacy installs ... even MDB2 seems unnecessary given native php functionality these days. But, since I didn't want to rewrite the whole DAL, I figured MDB2 was probably the path of least resistance. This is what it took to migrate DB => MDB2.

First you need to install the MDB2 classes:

```
shell> pear install MDB2
shell> pear install MDB2_Driver_mysql
```

Then you have to patch the source to actually use it:

```
shell> cd /your/daloradius/root
shell> find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/DB.php/MDB2.php/g' {} \;
```

Then you have to patch the source to account for some differences between DB and MDB2:

```
shell> find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/$dbSocket->escapeSimple/$dbSocket->escape/g' {} \;
shell> find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC/MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC/g' {} \;
shell> find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/$dbSocket->getOne/$dbSocket->queryOne/g' {} \;
shell> find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/$dbSocket->getCol/$dbSocket->queryCol/g' {} \;
shell> sed -i "s/MDB2::connect\x28\x24dbConnectString/MDB2::connect\x28\x24dbConnectString, array\x28\'result_buffering\' => true, \'portability\' => MDB2_PORTABILITY_ALL ^ MDB2_PORTABILITY_FIX_CASE\x29/g" library/opendb.php
```

I have tested most functionality and I'm not aware of any issues, though it's possible I missed something since I don't use the billing functionality. I noticed some preexisting warnings in the log relating to timezone, but otherwise it looks clean.

**Be very careful with these commands, they have the potential of being very destructive if they are not typed/copied correctly or get run in the wrong directory.**

Answer (score 0):

I had similar mistake, centos 7, daloradius-0.9-9.
I made next

```
yum install php-pear php-pear-DB
```

Now all Ok